# $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f R_1 f=0$ if $f\in L^2$ Riesz transform

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, integral-operators, singular-integral-equations

How can I see that? It seems that it has to do with the adjoint of the Riesz transform $R_1^*=-R_1$, but here we do not have the complex $L^2$ scalar product.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is real-valued?

Comment: Of course, for real-valued functions this is straightforward, but the statement was formulated in such a way that it seemed to suggest it holds in general.

Comment: As you pointed out, this is clear for real valued $f$, but then also $\int fR_1g=0$ for any two real valued functions by polarization. Now the complex valued case follows by splitting $f=f_1+if_2$.